# How to use cancel step of salesorder

Tags: dynamics-crm

My mission is to check a query before the salesorder is canceled if I get false I need to prevent the record from cancellation, when I debugged the step (salesorder - cancel) I couldn't get record id from the plugincontext (for my query) How can I get it ?

Comment: Which message did you register your plugin on ? setState ?

Answer (score 0):

I would Register plugin for cancel Salesorder. Registering plugin (Trigger) will act on server side and hence either from UI or from any background logic if someone is trying to cancel salesorder and it does not satisfy your condition. Action will not be performed.

Now on which message to register plugin. I am not completely sure, But I guess you will regitser for Entity Salesorder (Update) Event and filtering attribute (Status Reason).

In your Plugin (c#) you will check your criteria if it matches then block the cancel salesorder by throwing exception Else let it run without doing anything.

Comment: I used the cancel msg and plugin but can't get the record id, how do I get it ?

Comment: You need to go through [Plugin Tutorial for Dynamics 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/tutorial-write-plug-in)